# move class data members (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I want to know if I'm doing this right. I have a class that holds some data:

```
class Foo {
// ...
  Type a_;
  Type b_;
  Type c_;
};
```

And a different class that does something else, but is constructed using `class Foo`. So, I reckon declare a ctor like this:

```
class Bar {
  Type a_;
  Type b_;
  Type c_;
  AnotherType A_;
  AnotherType B_;
  // ...
public:
  typedef std::tuple<Type, Type, Type> Tuple;

  Bar(const Tuple&);
  Bar(Tuple&&);
};
```

I now need to create a `Foo` method that will return a tuple of the data members that `Bar` needs, which I can pass to `Bar`'s ctor. I also make a rvalue reference for `Tuple` because those data members of `class Foo` will not be needed anymore except via `class Bar`, so why bother copying data when I can move it?

So, I create methods in `class Foo` that will a return a `Tuple`. In particular, I need one that can be used by the `Bar` ctor that uses an rvalue reference. Is the following correct?

```
auto Foo::move_data() -> Tuple&& {
  return std::move( Tuple(a_, b_, c_) );
}
```

Or is this completely wrong? (Pointing out anything else stupid will also be appreciated. Of course, I've left out some typedefs and other unnecessary details.)

Comment: If `Foo` and `Bar` have data in common, why not put it in a same class `ABC` and use composition to have it both in `Foo` and `Bar`?

Comment: @JulienGuertault: Composition? Googling...

Comment: @JulienGuertault: Oh, you're asking why return tuples when I can return a `class ABC` object? Good question... (Ah, I got a good reason: so that I can learn and practise using some of the fancy new C++11 stuff!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it's not. This:

```
Tuple&& Foo::move_data() {
    return std::move( Tuple(a_, b_, c_) );
}
```

would copy your elements into a `Tuple`, and then `move` the `Tuple` itself... not your elements. What you *want* to do is move them *into* the `Tuple`, and then return it by value:

```
Tuple Foo::move_data() {
    return Tuple(std::move(a_), std::move(b_), std::move(c_) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I reckoned something like that made more sense, but I think I didn't return by value so the compiler complained about temporaries.

Answer (score 0):

It highly depends on the overall code, but from your problem description my question would be why not put a, b and c together in their own structure?

```
class Abc {
    Type a_;
    Type b_;
    Type c_;
};

class Foo {
    // ...
    Abc abc_;
    int somethingNotInBar_;
};

class Bar {
    Abc abc_;
    AnotherType A_;
    AnotherType B_;
    // ...
public:
    Bar(const ABC&);
};
```

Some advantages:

- It you would save the trouble of resorting to tuples;
- It would make the code easier to grasp (it's often more difficult to understand what a tuple is about, since names are lost in the process);
- It would make modification easier (for that day you realize you also need `d`, or you don't need `b` anymore).

Comment: An honest answer is: I am making the code on the fly and whilst I structured a lot of it, the fact that I need `Foo`'s data in `Bar` only occurred to me later on and I hacked something with tuples together instead of making a proper class for it! I _will_ probably be adding more data to the `Foo` -> `Bar` transfer, so a class _will_ be better. Thanks. On the plus side I am getting used to `std::tuple`...

Comment: Yes, being able to quickly play with code until you figure out how it's supposed to look like is important. It's unfortunate C++ lacks some flexibility in here; modifications cost time on syntactic details.